# datetime-local different format after selecting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

Given is an ionic app with `<input type='datetime-local'>` inputs which runs on an android system. The problem ist that the inputs have different formats after the user selects a Dates. `Start` is after the user selected a date and `Ende` is the default formatting. I already tried to add the `min`, `max` and `step` attribute.

The format without the miliseconds is the preferred one.

[image]

The Controller

```
$scope.event = {};
// Default dates
$scope.event.start = new Date();
$scope.event.end = new Date();
$scope.event.end.setHours($scope.event.start.getHours() + 2);
```

The HTML Part

```
<label class="item item-input underlinedInput equal-padding ">
    <span class="input-label">Start</span>
    <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Start" ng-model="event.start" step="1" min="1900-01-01T00:01:00" max="2900-01-01T23:59:59">
</label>
<label class="item item-input underlinedInput equal-padding ">
    <span class="input-label">Ende</span>
    <input type="datetime-local" placeholder="Ende" ng-model="event.end" step="1" min="1900-01-01T00:01:00" max="2900-01-01T23:59:59">
</label>
```

Comment: It would help if you used an unambiguous format. 03/04/2017 is 3 April for most, but 4 March for some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, i wrote a factory that solves my problem.

Instead of creating a date like `$scope.event.start = new Date()` just use `$scope.event.start = Tools.currentDate();`

```
.factory('Tools', function () {
    return {
      utcDate: function (date) {
          var d = new Date(date.replace(' ', 'T'));
          d.setTime(d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
          return d;
      },
      currentDate: function () {
          var d = new Date();
          var year = d.getFullYear();
          var month = this.leadingZero(d.getMonth());
          var day = this.leadingZero(d.getDate());
          var hour = this.leadingZero(d.getHours());
          var minutes = this.leadingZero(d.getMinutes());

          return this.utcDate(year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"T"+hour+":"+minutes+":00");
     },
     leadingZero: function(number){
         return ("0"+number).substr(-2,2);
     }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use date object like

```
$scope.event.start = new Date(2010, 11, 28, 14, 57);
```

refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0sbZHgRNu3MGqClQokDr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment JS and you will have a better control over date manipulation in your app. [moment js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
var startDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM A');
var endDate = moment().add(2, 'hours').format('DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM A')
```