# moment.js shows local time when running locally, but shows UTC on website

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, momentjs, utc

I'm using npm moment-timezone to log the time a user adds information to the database. This should log as local time, which it does when I serve locally. But when tested on my site, the time is in UTC format. Below is my code which again runs fine locally.  Any insight as to why it shows up UTC on the site is appreciated.

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var guessUserTimeZone = moment.tz.guess();
var date = moment().tz(guessUserTimeZone).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

edit: the desired result is to have the user's time show according to their time zone.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595766/datetime-local-different-format-after-selecting

Comment: i resolve this problem like this `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ')
   `

Comment: The server on which your site is running must be having time in UTC format. Server time zones may cause such kind of problems. Making server time zone same as your local time zone may help here.

Comment: @Mazz Admittedly, I didn't quite understand how to implement  your solution in my code.  But thanks everyone for the replies. I've given all three a try, and was unsuccessful